# why postgres takes an Access Exclusive Lock in many alter table commands?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

This is the latest release-version code of postgres(the link is [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c#L3389)):

```
    switch (cmd->subtype)
    {
            /*
             * These subcommands rewrite the heap, so require full locks.
             */
        case AT_AddColumn:  /* may rewrite heap, in some cases and visible
                             * to SELECT */
        case AT_SetTableSpace:  /* must rewrite heap */
        case AT_AlterColumnType:    /* must rewrite heap */
        case AT_AddOids:    /* must rewrite heap */
            cmd_lockmode = AccessExclusiveLock;
            break;
```

From PostgreSQL 9.4 on, we have catalog MVCC. My question is: why does it have to take the highest lock level while doing alter table commands? The comments in the code say that "These subcommands rewrite the heap, so require full locks." I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, most `ALTER TABLE` statements require an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock because not everything is strictly MVCC where the catalogs are concerned.

Usually that lock is very short, and you won't notice it.

Some variants have to rewrite the whole table, because they change the on-disk structure, for example:

- data type changes to a type with a different internal representation
- until v11, we had to rewrite the table if a `NOT NULL` column with a `DEFAULT` value was added to the table

There is an ongoing effort to reduce the locks.